# How to pass a parameter to a self executing anonymous function

Tags: javascript, express-4

**I have in my server.js this line of code:**

```
 require('../routes/allRoutes')(app)
```

**And this works fine when my allRoutes.js looks like this:**

```
 module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
      res.render ......
    });
 }
```

**But what if my allRoutes.js looks like this:**

```
  (function(allRoutes){

     app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.render .....
      });
  })(module.exports)
```

**How do I pass the app object in the anonymous, self executing function?**

Comment: Why not just use the first version?

Comment: What does your IIFE do with `allRoutes`? Why is that IIFE required at all?

Comment: I am following a tutorial by Shawn Wildermuth and he is using the second approach but he does not refactor, so I was trying to follow along but keep my files clean at the same time.

Comment: I dont see any advantages of using a iife in there, can you share that knowledge ?

Comment: It is not a matter of advantages or disadvantages, I was just trying to follow along Shawn's tutorial as he created the functions but call me OCD, I had to refactor my routes or I was going to climb the walls.

Comment: As we deal with nodejs modules, those IIFEs should be unncessary - just omit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nevermind, I figured it out:**

**1. server.js**

> ```
> require('./routes/allRoutes').init(app);
> ```

**2. allRoutes.js**

> ```
> (function(allRoutes) {
>   allRoutes.init = function(app) {
>     app.get("/", function (req, res) {
>       res.send('Hello You');
>     })
>   };
> })(module.exports);
> ```